# counting specific characters in string

Tags: java, string, search

I'm new at coding. If anyone can help me out: looking for a solution at this code, how to count how many times the "END" can be found at the randomly generated string.

Thank you guys!

```
public class Tombos {

  public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    PrintStream out1 = System.out;
    PrintStream out2 = new PrintStream(new File("out.txt"));

    String betuk = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";  
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<1000; i++) {  
      char random = betuk.charAt((int)(26*Math.random()));      
      out2.print(random);
    }
    Scanner beolvas = new Scanner(new File("out.txt"));
    String x = beolvas.next();
    if (x.contains("END")) {
      out1.print( "tartalmaz");    // include "END"
    } else {
      out1.print( "nem tartlmaz");  // not include "END"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the current issue?

Comment: well, the code is working as it is. I just cant found any solution to count how many those damn END can be find there.

Comment: You might want to flush or close `out2` before trying to read it.  Better yet, you could accumulate your random `char`s onto a `StringBuilder` and count the `"END"`s on that instead of involving the file-system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are a user of Apache Commons library, `StringUtils#countMatches` would do the job.

```
int count = StringUtils.countMatches(x, "END");
```

If not, I would probably use `String#split`

```
int count = x.split("END").length - 1;
```

It's a little bit ugly but it's easy and it's an one-liner:)

Comment: I was trying out this way also , StringUtils was not working (due to the miss of apache commons library?)  The String#splite works well! thans for help!

Comment: Yes, you need to have Apache Commons jar on the classpath in order to make StringUtils work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `countMatches` method of the `StringUtils` class.

```
int count = StringUtils.countMatches(x, "END");
```

It counts the number of times a String appears in another. [See documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#countMatches%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: `countMatches` is pretty cool, and probably the "correct" way to do it - I just figured he ought to see how to do it "manually" since he's new to programming.

Comment: @HawkWeisman True enough; coding up these kinds of convenience methods once can be a learning experience. Of course, after that, one would rather use the already implemented version.

Comment: @DennisMeng: oh, definitely! I just think it's important for beginning programmers to do it the "hard way" the first time so that they understand what the library methods are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a new int variable like `int count = 0;` then

```
 if (x.contains("END)) {
count++;
}
```

Everytime you find a "END" increment your variable and afterwards just print your variable.

Comment: This won't compile and this won't work... `increment your variable`? What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

First, make a new int variable. Let's call it `count`.
`int count;`

Then, in the body of the for loop, add one to `count` every time you find a matching string, like this: `count = count + 1`.

The program should look something like this:

```
int i;
int count;

for (i=0;i<1000;i++) {  
    char random=betuk.charAt((int)(26*Math.random()));      
    out2.print(random);
}

Scanner beolvas=new Scanner(new File("out.txt"));
String x=beolvas.next();

if (x.contains("END")) {
    out1.print( "tartalmaz");    // include "END"
    count = count + 1;           // add one to the count of matches
} else {
    out1.print( "nem tartlmaz");  // not include "END"
}
```

Comment: That's only going to count one occurrence of "END" per string (and, in this case, there's only one string to evaluate it against - no newlines in the file).

Comment: ah, you're right - I didn't read his code too closely. I'll add a `while` loop to the `if` statement to count every occurrence of `"END"`.

Comment: I was trying at this way first, then i noticed as writed above, its counted one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your exact intention is with the random string and the file scanner, but a basic way to do the string counting you asked about would be to use a regular expression (the [`Pattern` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)):

```
int endCount = 0;
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("END").matcher(x);
while (matcher.find()) {
    endCount++;
}
```

Note that if you're doing this somewhere in a loop or calling the method over and over, it'll eventually be more performant to make the `Pattern.compile()` call happen somewhere where it's only called once, and the resulting `Pattern` stored for reuse.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an algorithmic approach to it:

```
String x = "ENDDOFJUESADNFENDEJFDNFDENDD"; // arbitrary String

boolean moreMatches = true;
int index = 0, count = 0;

while(moreMatches) {

    if (x.indexOf("END", index) > -1)
    {
        index = x.indexOf("END", index) + 1;
        count++;
    } else {
        moreMatches = false;
    }
}

System.out.print(count); // prints 3
```

Please read the documentation for [<kbd>String.indexOf(String s, int fromIndex)</kbd>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to understand what I've done.

Every time I find the word `"END"` in the String, I search again, but this time search for `"END"` starting from the position *after* where I found it last time. When I can't find it anymore, I'm done the loop.